# error in SQL syntax when parsing xml files

Tags: php, sql, xml

I have tried to parsing data from url and this is part of xml data

```
-

    <players category="Attackers">
<player id="206651">
<name>Thapelo Tale</name>
<firstname>Thapelo</firstname>
<lastname>Tale</lastname>
<team></team>
<teamid></teamid>
<nationality>Lesotho</nationality>
<birthdate>22/04/1988</birthdate>
<age>25</age>
<birthcountry>Lesotho</birthcountry>
<birthplace>Maseru</birthplace>
<position>Attacker</position>
<height>169 cm</height>
<weight></weight>
<image>
```

and using this code

```
 <?php 
$xmlLinq_player=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");

foreach($xmlLinq_player->player as $player) { 
    $player_id = $player->attributes()->id;

    if($player_id){

        $team_name=mysql_real_escape_string($player->team);
        $team_id=mysql_real_escape_string($player->teamid);
        if($team_id =='' || !$team_id){
            $team_id=0;
        }

        $nationality=mysql_real_escape_string($player->nationality);
        $fullname=mysql_real_escape_string($player->name);
        $firstname=mysql_real_escape_string($player->firstname);
        $lastname=mysql_real_escape_string($player->lastname);
        $birthdate=$player->birthdate;
        $birthdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $birthdate)));
        $birthcountry=mysql_real_escape_string($player->birthcountry);
        $birthplace=mysql_real_escape_string($player->birthplace);
        $logo=$player->image;
        $position=mysql_real_escape_string($player->position);
        $height=$player->height;
        $weight=$player->weight;

        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO players (PlayerId,TeamId, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Nationality, BirthDate, BirthCountry, BirthPlace, PositionFull, Height,Weight,Photo)
                VALUES($player_id, $team_id, '$fullname', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$nationality', '$birthdate', '$birthcountry','$birthplace','$position','$height','$weight','$logo')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FullName = VALUES(FullName),FirstName = VALUES(FirstName), LastName = VALUES(LastName), Nationality = VALUES(Nationality), BirthDate = VALUES(BirthDate), BirthCountry = VALUES(BirthCountry),
                BirthPlace = VALUES(BirthPlace),PositionFull = VALUES(PositionFull),Height = VALUES(Height),Weight = VALUES(Weight),Photo = VALUES(Photo)");

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$result){
            $message = mysql_error() ;
            //$message = 'Whole Query: ' .$query;
            die($message);
        }

    }
}
}
 }
?>
```

then it give this problem
( You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\n , 'Thapelo Tale', 'Thapelo', 'Tale', 'Lesotho', '1970-01-01', 'Lesotho','M' at line 2 ) please help .. how to solve this problem thanks

Comment: First, don't ever concatenate strings when using SQL. Learn to use parameters. It will cause so much less issues and improve security. For example, here a single ' charater in any of your data would break your SQL. Check the full SQL clause being used and see what is the syntax error, but do change the code to use parameters. Not to mention mysql_-functions were deprecated *5 years ago*. Never use them. Use PDO or mysqli_-functions.

Comment: Instead of `if($team_id =='' || !$team_id){`, check `if(empty(trim(team_id))){`

Answer (score 0):

Check on duplicate key update syntax

```
    INSERT INTO players (PlayerId,TeamId, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Nationality, BirthDate, BirthCountry, BirthPlace, PositionFull, Height,Weight,Photo)
 VALUES($player_id, $team_id, '$fullname', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$nationality', '$birthdate', '$birthcountry','$birthplace','$position','$height','$weight','$logo')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FullName = '$FullName',FirstName ='$FirstName', LastName = '$LastName', 
    Nationality = '$Nationality', BirthDate = '$BirthDate', BirthCountry = '$BirthCountry',BirthPlace = '$BirthPlace',PositionFull = '$PositionFull',
    Height = '$Height',Weight = '$Weight',Photo = '$Photo'");
```